# Blackberry Enterprise Server Log Question

Tags: log-files, bes

I have a test Blackberry Enterprise Server Express 5.0.2 set up.  Currently I am dumping all of the logs, mostly coming from a custom template in Lotus Notes calendar, to try to trace down an error.  In searching through the logs I am noticing a discrepancy with **msgtype** but, I can't for the life of me figure out what the values mean.  The message looks like the following:

```
Constructing message (CMIME), size=1040, body size=2712, attachment data size=0, 
   unid=39B33CFEE3A86676543233AE0076765BA, RefId=-362616331, TransactionId=0,
   Tag=999, MsgType=0x1, RenderMode=0x601
```

What I am noticing is that on the one the works the **msgtype** is set to 0x0 and the one that doesn't it is set to 0x1.  The problem is is I have no idea what the data actually means.  Does anyone know what the MsgType is or where I can find a BES spec that states what they might be?

Comment: Anyone?  I can post more info if needed, I really need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the msgtype doesn't seem to have anything to do with my problem.  My Notes app was sending the Document within the NotesUIDocumentand not the NotesUIDocument itself.  Kind of weird that it works in Notes and not from the BES but, w/e I know where to fix is now anyways.